# lshw HWPath priority -- how to determine

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, ethernet

I have a project here at work where I'm attempting to definitively map ethernet MAC addresses to physical ports (IE card 1 port 0 is eth0 (mac xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) and a non-technical operator can look at that port descriptor and know exactly where a cable is plugged in on a box) for network devices in servers (arbitrary server vendors and models) using Linux, currently CentOS 6.6 without being required to crack the physical box.

The answer to this question probably lies in how Linux enumerates hardware, but I've neither found anything definitive asking the Googles nor been able to find anything definitive in man pages and the like. Finally, I don't believe in my skills at reading C to get the answer I need in the time I need it.

Using `lshw`:

```
root@E2APF77 (~)# lshw -c network -businfo
Bus info          Device  Class          Description
====================================================
pci@0000:06:00.0  eth0    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
pci@0000:06:00.1  eth1    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
pci@0000:16:00.0  eth2    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:16:00.1  eth3    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:16:00.2  eth4    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:16:00.3  eth5    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
                  usb0    network        Ethernet interface
```

which is interesting, but I prefer to see the hw path, so I run:

```
root@E2APF77 (~)# lshw -c network -short -businfo
H/W path             Device  Class          Description
=======================================================
/0/100/2/0           eth0    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
/0/100/2/0.1         eth1    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
/0/100/1c.4/0        eth2    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.1      eth3    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.2      eth4    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.3      eth5    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/1                   usb0    network        Ethernet interface
```

Now this is interesting to me, but I'm not sure if I'm seeing the context I need. So, running the following gives me better context:

```
root@E2APF77 (~)# lshw -short -businfo -c bridge
H/W path             Device  Class          Description
=======================================================
/0/100                       bridge         Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DMI2
/0/100/1                     bridge         Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/2                     bridge         Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2
/0/100/3                     bridge         Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3
/0/100/1c                    bridge         C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.3                  bridge         C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.3/0                bridge         Renesas Technology Corp.
/0/100/1c.3/0/0              bridge         Renesas Technology Corp.
/0/100/1c.3/0/0/0            bridge         Renesas Technology Corp.
/0/100/1c.3/0/1              bridge         Renesas Technology Corp.
/0/100/1c.4                  bridge         C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1f                    bridge         C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller
```

OK. I like this. Now I see that the following:

```
/0/100/2                     bridge         Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2
/0/100/2/0           eth0    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
/0/100/2/0.1         eth1    network        Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2


/0/100/1c.4                  bridge         C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0        eth2    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.1      eth3    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.2      eth4    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
/0/100/1c.4/0.3      eth5    network        NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

...where the first card is on port 2 of the `Xeon E5` bridge and the second card is on port `1c.4` of the `C610/X99` bridge (if I'm even using the correct naming of the nomenclature. Please forgive me if I'm not). I have no easy way of validating the locations of where the hardware is plugged in and I currently have no knowledge of the specifics of how these machines are built without reading documentation.

So, can one assert or assume that the way Linux is enumerating the hardware in the box is in some priority that we can use to determine the physical ports to an arbitrary number of arbitrary brand of network cards in arbitrary boxen? I'm assuming I'm barking up the right tree, but something isn't passing the smell test for me on this.